Traer datos según mes de tres hojas
Buenos dias estimados,
Quisiera que me ayudaran con lo siguiente, tengo una hoja donde debo extraer datos de las columnas N, O, P y R (Molinos 3 y 4) y  K, l , M y O (Molino 5) si los hay segun mes solicitado en la celda C2 de la hoja Resistencias de tres procesos para 3 molinos. La idea es que me traiga los días del mes solicitado, el tipo de cemento y las resistencias.
Las resistencias están en en las columnas N, O, P y R para los molinos 3 y 4. Y para el molino 5 están en lasa columnas K, l , M y O.
Yo tengo una macro pero solo me trae los datos del día que solicito.
Adjunto los archivos
Saludos y espera de sus valiosos comentarios.
